# Alternative url to my Pythonanywhere website?

Tags: pythonanywhere

The normal url to my website is :

```
http://<username>.pythonanywhere.com
```

Is there a way to to access the site using the IP address of the pythonanywhere server, something like :

```
http://50.19.109.98/~<username>
```

Comment: StackOverflow is intended for programming questions, not web hosting or network questions. You'll get better results at ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. You can hit `http://50.19.109.98` and set the host header to `<username>.pythonanywhere.com`. Otherwise the webserver (that serves a large number of sites) has no idea which site you're trying to access.

Comment: Thanks ! Works like a charm ! I had problem to access my site via GPRS. For those who are interested, the request is: GET /<path_to_url> HTTP/1.1[CR][LF]Host: <username>.pythonanywhere.com[CR][LF][CR][LF]